# Conceptual undestanding of a pull-back in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have recently started learning a bit of differential geometry and have reached the point of learning about diffeomorphisms and pull-backs.
In the notes that I've been reading the author states that:

$``$Let $f: M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. A diffeomorphism $\phi :M\rightarrow M$ changes $f$ into a different function, called the *pull-back* of $f$, and denoted as $\phi^{\ast}f$. It is defined such that given two points $p\in M$ and $q=\phi (p)\in M$, $$ (\phi^{\ast}f)(p)=f(q)=f(\phi (p))$$ i.e. $$(\phi^{\ast}f)=f\circ\phi"$$

By this, is it meant that the pull-back function evaluated at the original point $p\in M$ is equal to the "original" function evaluated at the point $q\in M$ mapped to by the diffeomorphism? 
Is the reason for defining such a notion so that one can compare the values of a function evaluated at different points on the manifold?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Smooth}[1]{\mathscr{C}^{\infty}(#1)}$Your understanding of the definition of $\phi^{*}f$ is perfectly correct. As for the "reason", it's probably more productive to ask "how do pullbacks arise in theory and practice", and to treat each "satisfying occurrence" as a "reason". :)

I Am Not A Historian of Mathematics, but probably the origin of the definition was the wish to parametrize a piece of a manifold, i.e., to look at diffeomorphisms $\phi^{-1}:\phi(U) \to U$ (with $\phi: U \subset M \to \Reals^{n}$ a coordinate chart on $M$), then to express questions about calculus on $M$ as questions about ordinary multivariable calculus in the open set $\phi(U) \subset \Reals^{n}$.

Another reason (though probably a secondary or tertiary reason) is to study what parts of differential and integral calculus are diffeomorphism-invariant, a.k.a., independent of the choice of coordinate system. Examples include velocites of curves (but not accelerations, which require additional structure, such as a Riemannian metric), and exterior calculus (differential forms, Stokes' theorem). If you're looking for an additional reference, Spivak's *Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Volume I*, is quite good. (I believe there are many excellent newer books, as well; my bibliographic knowledge is rather out-of-date.)

A more modern "reason" for looking at pullbacks is the prospect of replacing a smooth manifold (or a locally-compact Hausdorff space) by its algebra $\Smooth{M}$ of smooth functions. As you've noted, a diffeomorphism $\phi:M \to M$ induces an automorphism of the algebra $\Smooth{M}$. A point $p$ of $M$ corresponds in this picture to the maximal ideal of functions vanishing at $p$. Many constructs of differential geometry can be formulated similarly in terms of algebras on $M$. This idea is Deep, giving rise to the scheme-theoretic viewpoint in algebraic geometry, and to non-commutative geometry.

Incidentally, the definition of pullback of a function makes perfect sense for a smooth mapping of manifolds $\phi:M \to N$, not merely for diffeomorphisms $\phi:M \to M$. Generally, the pullback $\phi^{*}:\Smooth{N} \to \Smooth{M}$ isn't invertible. (If $\phi$ is a constant mapping, for example, the pullback amounts to evaluation.) Pullback by a diffeomorphism, however, *is* invertible; the inverse is $(\phi^{-1})^{*}:\Smooth{M} \to \Smooth{N}$, pullback by the inverse map.

Answer (score 2):

Yes to 'By this...' and what follows.

I guess the reason for defining such a notion is first of all, that $\phi$ defines a a natural map from $C^\infty(M)$ to $C^\infty(M)$ for which one wants have a name, and which has certain formal properties which behave well from a functiorial point of view (the concept is not limited to the situation you are looking at).

As a first generalization consider a diffeomorphism $\phi: M\rightarrow N$. The you get a pullback $\phi:C^\infty(N)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ by the same definition.